# CMake find_package and NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH

Tags: c++, cmake

i'm using cmake find_package to find JPEG library to be used in my application. I do have two installations of that library, the system one, located on:

```
libjpeg: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
```

and another custom located on:

```
/my/jpeg/instalation/lib/libjpeg.so
```

and I want to decide what version should I use by command line.

For example to use the custom one my cmake command is:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/my/jpeg/instalation
```

and to look only for system ones cmake command will be:

```
cmake ..
```

and my CMakeLists.txt has something like this when CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is defined:

```
find_package(JPEG NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH REQUIRED)
```

and when no CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is defined:

```
find_package(JPEG REQUIRED)
```

But with NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH no library is found... i was assuming that with this flag the system paths were ignored, but it seems that the ones declared in the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH are also discarded...

Basically i want when CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is specified that no system libraries are considered and when no CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is specified the system libraries should be consider...

the only way that i can see this to work for custom paths is to do something like this:

```
find_package(JPEG PATHS ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

but this also does not find... i'm totally lost with this find_package behaviour...

PS: i'm using cmake version 3.10.2 and the error is always:

```
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):                             
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "JPEG" with any of
  the following names:                                                      

    JPEGConfig.cmake                                                        
    jpeg-config.cmake                                                       

  Add the installation prefix of "JPEG" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set         
  "JPEG_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "JPEG"   
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been       
  installed.
```

---

### Update

What I failed to realize is that find_package settins are only for find_package funcionality, this is, searching for FindJPEG.cmake or JPEGconfig.cmake scripts and not the contents of this scripts.
What I want is only acomplished using the specific functions that find paths or files, like for example on Tom example but using find_library like this:

```
set(CUSTOM_JPEG_PATH ON CACHE BOOL "use only custom paths")
set(JPEG_NAMES ${JPEG_NAMES} jpeg libjpeg)
if(CUSTOM_JPEG_PATH)
        #find_package(JPEG REQUIRED
        find_library(JPEG_LIBRARY NAMES ${JPEG_NAMES}
           NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH
           NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH
        )
else()
        #find_package(JPEG REQUIRED
        find_library(JPEG_LIBRARY NAMES ${JPEG_NAMES}
                )
endif()
```

And this work like expected (instead of given the root folder of custom installation i need to give the exact location - /my/jpeg/instalation/lib - in order to work). 
But this is not what I want, I do not want to rewrite all the FindXXX.cmake scripts in order to get what I want, these find scripts have more detail on them dependencies, compilation flags, etc... so I'm guessing there is no way of doing what I want using only find_package(...)...

Comment: Have you tried `find_library`?

Comment: I know that find_library has the same settings (or almost) but what i'm asking is without changing the FindXXX.cmake script where the find_library calls are... but it seems that these settings on the find_package function are only for locate the module or scripts responsible to find the libraries or paths.. the internals aren't affected by the find_package settings...

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to work just without your `NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` approach. Just use `find_package(JPEG REQUIRED)`. If `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is set, then find_package will look into that directory first.

If you want it specifically you could specify `PATHS` or `HINTS` for your `find_package`-call:

```
set(CUSTOM_JPEG_PATH "" CACHE STRING "path to custom installation of libjpeg")
if(CUSTOM_JPEG_PATH)
        find_package(JPEG REQUIRED 
            PATHS ${CUSTOM_JPEG_PATH} 
            NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH
        )
else()
        find_package(JPEG REQUIRED) #default search
endif()
```

Comment: Hi Tom, indeed you are right, but the problem is that when I specify the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH i wanted that only the libraries found on the path specified should be used, but what i see is that for example if the find package script acount for debug and release libraries and if i only got one on the specified path and the system got the other the script will consider both, and i only want the specified on the path even if one of the configuration is not available...

Comment: I see. But still you could use my suggested approach with `PATHS` in combination with your `NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH`-specification

Comment: Hi Tom, see my update, the find_library or find_path inside the FindXXX.cmake script are not affected by the settings that I set on the find_package... that's my conclusion, so what i want can't be really acomplished like i desired...

Answer (score 0):

Use vcpkg. The easiest is through [project_options](https://github.com/cpp-best-practices/project_options/#project_options), which automatically sets up vcpkg and includes its toolchain.

vcpkg overrides the default CMake paths and environment variables such that the vcpkg provided paths are preferred over the system ones.

vcpkg.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vcpkg/master/scripts/vcpkg.schema.json",
  "name": "myproject",
  "version-string": "0.1.0",
  "builtin-baseline": "70d3ac3a1754fffcd7d099b2b268bf7dfe70c162",
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "name": "libjpeg-turbo",
      "version>=": "2.0.6"
    }
  ]
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

# Add project_options v0.19.0
# https://github.com/cpp-best-practices/project_options
# Change the version in the following URL to update the package (watch the releases of the repository for future updates)
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(_project_options URL https://github.com/cpp-best-practices/project_options/archive/refs/tags/v0.19.0.zip)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(_project_options)
include(${_project_options_SOURCE_DIR}/Index.cmake)

run_vcpkg()

project(myproject LANGUAGES CXX C)

project_options(
  # all the options you need
)

add_executable(myprogram main.cpp)

find_package(JPEG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${JPEG_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR})
```